# How to get pin codes without zeros in it?

Tags: mysql

Write a query to display the customer_id,customer full name ,city,pincode,and order details (order id, product class desc, product desc, subtotal(product_quantity * product_price)) for orders shipped to cities whose pin codes do not have any 0s in them. Sort the output on customer name and subtotal. (52 ROWS) [NOTE: TABLE TO BE USED - online_customer, address, order_header, order_items, product, product_class].

These are the attributes of each table:

Address- ADDRESS_ID, ADDRESS_LINE1,ADDRESS_LINE2,CITY,STATE,PINCODE,COUNTRY

ONLINE_CUSTOMER- CUSTOMER_ID, CUSTOMER_FNAME, CUSTMER_LNAME, CUSTOMER_EMAIL,CUSTOMER_PHONE, ADDRESS_ID, CUSTOMER_CREATION_DATE,CUSTOMER_USERNAME, CUSTOMER_GENDER

ORDER_HEADER- ORDER_ID, CUSTOMER_ID, ORDER_DATE, ORDER_STATUS, PAYMENT_MODE, PAYMENT_DATE, ORDER_SHIPMENT_DATE,SHIPPER_ID

ORDER_ITEMS- ORDER_ID, PRODUCT_ID, PRODUCT_QUANTITY

PRODUCT- PRODUCT_ID, PRODUCT_DESC, PRODUCT_CLASS_CODE, PRODUCT_PRICE, PRODUCT_QUANTITY_AVAIL, LEN, WIDTH, HEIGHT, WEIGHT

PRODUCT_CLASS- PRODUCT_CLASS_CODE, PRODUCT_CLASS_DESC

Can anyone help me on how to filter pincodes without any zeros in it and order status as shipped.

Comment: Home work related questions must include a reasonable attempt at solving the problem, otherwise we would do the home work instead of you and that's not the point!

Answer (score 0):

Test if no zeros exist

where length(replace(pincode,'0','')) = length(pincode)

or

where instr(pincode,'0') = 0

or you could use regex or test valid pincodes by downloading and validating